# Get command line cucumber tag

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I have a feature that runs against 3 different tags. Some scenarios run against all three tags, some two, some against only one.

```
@build_1 @build_2
Scenario: Test Case 1
Given I am on the home page
And I click the X button
Then I must see the text "function not available"

@build_1
Scenario: Test Case 2
Given I am on the home page
And I click the Y button
Then I must see the text "You pushed the Y button"

@build_2 @build_3
Scenario: Test Case 3
Given I am on the home page
And I click the Y button
Then I must see the text "function not available"

@build_3
Scenario: Test Case 4
Given I am on the home page
And I click the X button
Then I must see the text "Hey, this is neat!"

@build_1 @build_2 @build_3
Scenario: Test Case 5
Given I am on the home page
And I click the Z button
Then I must see the text "You pushed the Z button"
```

I run the scenario using three different commands:

```
cucucmber features/my_test.feature --tags @build_1
cucucmber features/my_test.feature --tags @build_2
cucucmber features/my_test.feature --tags @build_3
```

I have drastically simplified my code, given the time it takes to switch between builds it is necessary for me to run tests this way.

Is there any way to tell which tag the current run was called with? Using

```
scenario.source_tag_names
```

gives all the tags for a given scenario, I am looking for the one tag that was specified on the command line. If I run

```
cucucmber features/my_test.feature --tags @build_2
```

For scenario 1 i get

```
scenario.source_tag_names = ["@build_1", "@build2", "@build_3"]
```

I want something that just gives @build_2.

In the end what I am looking for is a way to ensure that all the scenarios have run against all their respective tags.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Are you concerned that this isn't happening?

Comment: To be honest, it is a very complicated system where over one hundred tests will be run against over 30 configurations(I used the term build to simplify the question). I think it would be wise bookkeeping to know how many configurations my test was supposed to run against, and if it actually ran on them.

Comment: In that case you might store the test results then grep them for the counts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [AfterConfiguration hook](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Hooks#afterconfiguration)

```
AfterConfiguration do |config|
  puts config.tag_expressions
end
```

Comment: This is a great answer. I'm finding the AfterConfiguration hook very useful.